# HTTP Error 401.2 When Issuing HttpRequest

Tags: c#

I'm trying to post to an asp.net webpage and receive the resulting xml.

Here's my code:

```
        Uri url = new Uri("https://www.dmr.nd.gov/oilgas/feeservices/getcpfilesxml.asp");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Credentials = nc;
        request.Method = "POST";

        Byte[] postBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("FileNumber=04113");
        request.ContentLength = postBuffer.Length;
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; Charset=UTF-8";

        using (Stream postData = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postData.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

When I run this, I get an HTTP Error 401.2 error explaining: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied because your Web browser is sending a WWW-Authenticate header field that the Web server is not configured to accept.

When using the asp.net page on the website, this is the header info I get in Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 May 2012 15:34:44 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 4325
Content-Type: text/xml; Charset=UTF-8
Cache-control: private
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

With this Auth info:

- No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present.
- No WWW-Authenticate Header is present.

When running my application, this is the header info I get in Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 May 2012 17:18:04 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 124
Content-Type: text/xml; Charset=UTF-8
Cache-control: private
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDASADTBCS=JEBNCDNDNEPNLEBIEAFHENJF; path=/
X-Pad: avoid browser bug
```

With this Auth info:

- No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present.
- WWW-Authenticate Header is present: Basic realm="www.dmr.nd.gov"

How do I avoid that WWW-Authenticate Header being pushed over?

Comment: What is `nc` in `request.Credentials = nc;` ?

Comment: I pass credentials with the request, but I removed them from the post for privacy purposes. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: But why do you do that if you want to avoid the WWW-Authenticate header? They are related...

Comment: Hmm... this sounds like a catch 22. I need the credentials to log in to the website, but it seems when the asp.net page is run in the browser, it allows getcpfilesxml.asp to be run because it's on the server. When I run getcpfilesxml.asp in my application, I'm not allowed without the credentials. If I do I get the WWW-Authenticate header...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I figured out the authentication issue wasn't really my problem. Apparently I wanted a GET operation, and I was running a POST operation.